# Receive the time now in an updated manner

Tags: java

I am performing an operation in Java code, this is the code I am performing:

```
public String GetTheTimeNow() {
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
   LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
 return dtf.format(now);
}
```

And I want the return in function to run every second so that the discussion is always updated.  how do I do it?

Comment: If you only want the time, you should use [LocalTime.now()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#now()), not LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way apart from what Phil Freihofner mentioned, call your `GetTheTimeNow()` from calling method & use `Thread.sleep`:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (;;) {
        System.out.println(new Test().GetTheTimeNow());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }       
}

public String GetTheTimeNow() {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    return dtf.format(now);
}}
```

Comment: Okay .. sorry for the ignorance, but I'm just starting in Java, and I'm using code to build extensions to a site called Coder, and the function I brought earlier, it performs an action name, what code will I have to put inside the function to keep the hour updated every second?

Comment: @avi_770 , didn't get your question. Can you please rephrase it.

Comment: There is a site called kodular where you can build applications without code, but, there is not everything ... so you can develop extensions to add, I want to develop an extension of displaying the time now. And it really shows me the time, but it does not update it for me, it shows the time when I entered the screen, and I want the time to always be updated. Because at the moment the clock does not move, but as soon as I enter the screen it remains about the time I entered the screen. And I want it updated ...

Comment: I did this and it does not work:
```@SimpleFunction(description = "Get the time now")
public String GetTheTimeNow() {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    for (;;) {
            return dtf.format(now);
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: I get the error:

Comment: Started Compiling Project GetTime
Buildfile: /compiler/android/build.xml

javac:
[mkdir] Created dir: /compiler/android/build/wLYld/classes
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /compiler/android/build/wLYld/classes
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
[javac] /compiler/android/src/wLYld/Get/Time/extension/avi/GetTime.java:57: error: class, interface, or enum expected
[javac] public void TestEvent(){
[javac] ^

Comment: [javac] /compiler/android/src/wLYld/Get/Time/extension/avi/GetTime.java:59: error: class, interface, or enum expected
[javac] }
[javac] ^
[javac] 2 errors
[javac] 1 warning

Comment: Can you please let us know  if you are using proper JRE to execute above code?

Comment: Do not know, what does it mean?  (I'm new to Java.)

Comment: Which library should be imported?

Comment: The above mentioned code will work with any latest JRE (Java runtime envirnoment) versions 1.8 or higher. You might want to look at how to run java program here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-run-a-java-program#:~:text=%20How%20to%20run%20a%20java%20program%20,the%20result%20printed%20on%20the%20window.%20More%20

Comment: Yes, but I'm getting an error on this line, are you sure you do not need any directory for this? This is the error:

Comment: :/compiler/android/build/WcPcv/classes/ComponentsTranslation.java
[javac] /compiler/android/src/WcPcv/Get/Time/extension/avi/GetTime.java:47: error: unreachable statement
[javac] Thread.sleep(1000);
[javac] ^
[javac] /compiler/android/src/WcPcv/Get/Time/extension/avi/GetTime.java:47: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[javac] Thread.sleep(1000);
[javac] ^
[javac] 2 errors

Comment: Do you want me to forward this conversation to chat?

Comment: Please do one thing, Exactly copy paste my entire code; name that class as  `Test` & try to run & tell us what is error. It looks like you are trying to incorporate changes into your code but receiving error.

Answer (score 0):

There are three different "timers" that can be launched: [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html), [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html), or [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

With each you can schedule a task to execute periodically.